# Medians by group in R

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

In the code below, I was wondering if anyone would have any insight on how to use plyr or data.table to elegantly compute med.val2.

```
library(plyr)
```

Setup example data

```
data <- data.frame(id1 = 1:20, id2 = rep(letters[1:4], 5), vals=rnorm(20))
```

First calculate group medians by loop

```
data$med.val <- rep(0, 20)
for (ind in 1:20) data$med.val[ind] <- median(data$vals[data$id2==data$id2[ind]])
```

Now using plyr

```
data <- ddply(data, .(id2), mutate, med.val.plyr=median(vals))
```

Should be equal

```
all.equal(data$med.val, data$med.val.plyr)
```

Median of rows with the same id2, excluding the focal row

```
# Median of values corresponding to 
# data$id1!=data$id1[ind] & data$id2==data$id2[ind]
data$med.val2 <- rep(0, 20)
for (ind in 1:20) data$med.val2[ind] <- median(data$vals[data$id1!=data$id1[ind] & data$id2==data$id2[ind]])
```

In R, I typically use plyr or data.table to efficiently calculate values by group. My actual data and functions are more complicated but identical in structure: I need to calculate a function using data from rows with a common identifier, excluding the focal row. And I cannot figure out a way to do that efficiently and elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution with data table:

```
dt = data.table(data)
dt[,med.val3 := sapply(.SD$id1, function(x) median(.SD[id1!=x,vals])), by=id2]
```

On edit: this solution, along with the ones by @shadow are relatively concise and elegant.  They are also going to as efficient as you can probably hope for from this kind of solution. However, computing any leave-one-out statistic is going to be an O(n^2) operation (or worse) unless you can code up a more efficient implementation.  For things like average and median, this is pretty straightforward, for example:

```
looMedian<-function(x){
  rng<-range(x)
  bigMedian<-median(c(x,rng[2]+1))
  smallMedian<-median(c(x,rng[1]-1))
  med<-median(x)
  ret<-ifelse(x<med,bigMedian,smallMedian)  
  wm<-which(x==med)
  if(length(wm)==0)
    return(ret)
  ret[wm]<-median(x[-wm[1]])
  ret
}
```

This is much more efficient than the naive solution:

```
looMedianSlow<-function(x){
  sapply(seq_along(x),function(z) median(x[-z]))
}


> xx<-rnorm(100)
> all.equal(looMedianSlow(xx),looMedian(xx))
[1] TRUE
> xx<-rnorm(101)
> all.equal(looMedianSlow(xx),looMedian(xx))
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(looMedianSlow(xx),looMedian(xx))
Unit: microseconds
              expr      min       lq    median        uq       max neval
 looMedianSlow(xx) 5174.193 5264.951 5308.5075 5398.6950 44771.062   100
     looMedian(xx)  241.462  248.513  260.0685  278.3615  3495.796   100
```

Whether something like this is possible in your case will depend on what statistic you are trying to compute.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for an auxillary function and then use the same method as in `median`.

```
med2 <- function(x) sapply(seq_along(x), function(ind) median(x[-ind]))
data <- ddply(data, .(id2), mutate, med.val2.plyr=med2(vals))
all.equal(data$med.val2, data$med.val2.plyr)
```

Or the `data.table` way of doing the same:

```
dt <- data.table(data, key="id2")
med2 <- function(x) sapply(seq_along(x), function(ind) median(x[-ind]))
dt[, med.val2.dt:=med2(vals), by=id2]
all.equal(dt$med.val2, dt$med.val2.dt)
```